# Show that if a space $X$ is not path-connected, then the suspension $\Sigma X$ is not simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> For a topological space $X,$ we defined the suspension $\Sigma X$ as the quotient $(X \times I) / \sim,$ where
> $$
> (x, t) \sim(y, s) \Longleftrightarrow s=t \wedge(s \in\{0,1\} \vee y=x)
> $$
> Show that if $X$ is not path-connected, then $\Sigma X$ is not simply connected.

Please give some comment on the proof below.

My idea for the proof is to see a loop in any product space $X_1 \times X_2$ as the product of a loop in $X_1$ and a loop in $X_2$: if $\gamma_1: I \to X_1$ is a loop with $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_1(1) = x_1$, and $\gamma_2: I \to X_2$ is a loop with $\gamma_2(0) = \gamma_2(1) = x_2$, then $\gamma(s) = (\gamma_1(s),\gamma_2(s))$ is a loop in $X_1 \times X_2$ with base point $(x_1,x_2)$. Homotopies of $\gamma$ can likewise be decomposed into homotopies of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.

Now a loop in $\Sigma X$ that should not be homotopic to a point can be constructed as follows. Since $X$ is not path-connected, $X$ has two distinct path-components $C_1$ and $C_2$. In $C_1 \times I$, let $\alpha_1$ be a path from a point in $C_1 \times \{0\}$ to a point in $C_1 \times \{1\}$, which exists since both $C_1$ and $I$ are path-connected. Also let $\alpha_2$ be a path from a point in $C_2 \times \{1\}$ to a point in $C_2 \times \{0\}$. Since $(C_1 \times {0}) \sim (C_2 \times {0}) =: \hat{0}$ and $(C_1 \times {1}) \sim (C_2 \times {1}) =: \hat{1}$ in the construction of $\Sigma X$, $\alpha_1 \cdot \alpha_2 =: \alpha$ is a loop in $\Sigma X$.

If $\alpha$ is homotopic to a point, then by the decomposition of $\gamma$ above, $\alpha$ can be seen as the product of two loops, one in the “$X$”-coordinate and one in the “$I$”-coordinate, with one extra details: for some $s \in I$, if $\gamma(s)$ passes through $\hat{0}$ or $\hat{1}$, then the projection of $\gamma$ into $X$ sends $\gamma(s)$ to either $C_1$ or $C_2$, but not both, since $X$ is not path-connected (and $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$). But then $\gamma$ would be discontinuous in the “$X$”-coordinate.

Comment: I think the argument for the fact that no homotopy exists isn’t good enough. If $X$ is two points (so the suspension is the circle), it would imply the non-contractibility of the standard loop on the circle, which looks a more technical result than that.

Comment: Would you say the decomposition is problematic, or is the argument that the loop in the $X$-coordinate is discontinuous not strong enough?

Comment: The issue is that there is no global well-defined $X$-coordinate map.

Comment: At this point we’ve only covered some point-set topology, fundamental groups (mostly of $S^1$ and other not too complicated spaces), some category theory and universal properties of the product and quotient, and Borsuk-Ulam theorem. We’re setting the stage for Van Kampen theorem.

Comment: Ah. Because there’s a very short argument with singular homology...